# How to implement per-app VPN feature on Wireguard for Windows Platform

Tags: windows, vpn, wireguard

I've developed a VPN agent using Wireguard for the Windows platform and now I'm looking to implement a per-app VPN feature within my application. I want to enable specific applications to route their traffic through the VPN while leaving other applications unaffected.

I'd appreciate guidance on how to achieve this. Are there any specific Wireguard configurations or APIs I should be aware of to implement per-app VPN on Windows? Any insights, code examples, or resources to help me get started would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I already have an MDM server which will push the necessary profile for per-app VPN.